# Incorporating windows java program into android build

Tags: java, android, regex

I have been trying to incorporate this windows java program into android build but I have not been able to successfully achieve that. The program reverses inputted string word for word. How do I get the android to reverse sentences just like the code does with the windows

**Check out the code**

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class SubActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
}

//From here is problem. Please help me in fixing it 
public void RevOnClick(View view)
{
    EditText main2EditText1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.main2EditText1);
    String sen = main2EditText1.getText().toString();
    String[] senRev = sen.split("\\b");

    for (int n = senRev.length - 1; n >= 0; n--)  
    {

        TextView main2TextView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.main2TextView1);
        main2TextView1.setText(senRev[n]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop you're setting the text of your component to the letter you're currently iterating through. By reversing the `String` using [`StringBuilder.reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)and passing it only once to `setText()` it should work correctly:

```
public void RevOnClick(View view)
{
    EditText main2EditText1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.main2EditText1);
    String sen = main2EditText1.getText().toString();
    String[] senRev = sen.split("\\b");

    // use a StringBuilder to assemble the reversed sentence
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int n = senRev.length - 1; n >= 0; n--)  
    {       
        // append each word 
        result.append(senRev[n]);

        if (n > 0) {
            // if there are more words add a ' '
            result.append(" ");
        }
    }

    TextView main2TextView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.main2TextView1);
    main2TextView1.setText(result.toString());
}
```

Comment: Mr Oschlueter, thanks for your contributions. Your code did reverse the text by the character and not by the words. The program should output a complete reversal of a sentence eg. "cool dude" should output "dude cool" not "looc edud". I was able to get it right building the program in the windows console, but making the same on android is the hard part. Please do continue to help if more ideas come to heart. Thanks a million

Comment: And also please clarify what the problem is. Based on your code I would assume it only shows a single word instead of the reversed sentence, is that correct?

Comment: Kool!! It worked...its now outputting the sentence reversal. Thanks a million. Meanwhile in the code i changed the                       if (result > 0) to if (result != null && result.equals("")) ......as the latter returned an error. Thanks again though, all hail

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I fixed that mistake, it's supposed to check `n` of course, not `result`! :-) Good luck!

Comment: Would you help me more on the other question about "processing all email on one text field"?